# Phone keeps turning on and back off. What do I do?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, recovery-mode, reboot

This morning, I turned on my mobile, which had been fully charged during the night. It displayed the usual white «Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo  powered by android» thing, but then it vanished, then it reappeared, and it has been doing this throughout the day, for all I know. I tried googling, and found out about:

- FastBoot, which is acheived by pressing Vol+,Vol-,Power all at once; this does nothing at all on my device;
- Recovery boot, which is acheived by pressing Vol+,Power,Home all at once; this displays a small blue «RECOVERY BOOTING…» on the top-left corner, but only if the phone is connected to a charger, otherwise nothing happens;
- Hard Reset, but this seems to be impossible, as it requires (see here) the phone to be completely off, which is, at present, simply impossible.

Removing the battery won't do anything: I tried that several times, but as soon as I put it back, it goes back to doing the above. Also, connecting to the charger makes the «Samsung Galaxy [etc]» display like 2 or 3 times longer.

What should I do about this? What is wrong with my phone?

**Update**

Following @MatthewRead's comment, I tried Vol-,Power,Home. Something flashed on the screen, and then back to on-off-on-off. This is a frame of a short movie I captured with another mobile:

[image]

Sorry for the name of the movie showing up and hiding «Warning». I just tried Vol+ as that screen suggests, and now the screen shows up no more. One thing is sure: holding down that combination now stops it from on-off-on-off-ing, but as soon as I release, we're back there.

**Update 2**

I tried other key combinations, and this is what I found out:

- Vol+ -> Recovery booting;
- Vol+,Home -> Recovery booting;
- Vol+,Power -> Recovery booting;
- Vol+,Power,Home -> Recovery booting;
- Power,Vol- -> screen above;
- Vol-,Home -> screen above;
- Vol-,Power,Home -> screen above;
- Vol- -> screen above.

The last two have not always happened, but maybe I thought I was pressing when I actually wasn't. The screen says to hit Vol+ or Vol-, but none of those does anything.

**Update 3**

Someone suggested I scrape the battery contacts, I did it, and now the mobile seems to be working again. So this apparently saved me the trouble of flashing, though I have the firmware downloaded in case something goes wrong.

Comment: You should be able to do a Factory Reset from Recovery Mode.  A hard reset refers to either a full power cycle (which you've done) or a Factory Reset.  You might want to try other key combinations to get into Download Mode (the alternative to Fastboot used by Samsung phones) -- it's probably Vol- + Power + Home.

Comment: @MatthewRead tried that combination. Something flashed for a few seconds, I was only able to read «Warning, a custom OS might», and then it went back to on-off-on-off.

Comment: @MatthewRead see updates.

Comment: Please revive the external SD card and see. I had a somewhat similar situation which got fixed by changing SD card on a different phone

Comment: @beeshyams What do you mean by "revive the SD card"? Yesterday's trials were done while another device was up and running with my SD card, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Firstly sorry for typo meant remove not revive. In my case also the sd card was running fine with other device (till today) but for some reason that sd card didn't agree with the phone and causing similar problem- sharing a possibility, that's all

Answer (score 1):

1. Try this take out your battery
2. Wait for 10 seconds
3. Re Insert the battery without pressing the power button 
   if it turns on itself (witout pressing the power button( then it would be hardware problem. Just clean it with alcohol or tinner and keep pressing on it to clean the inside of your power swith or if not just replace your power button.
4. If not auto turn on after inserting the battery then its software problem. Just download the official firmware ang flash your phone via odin.

Answer (score 0):

**From Experience** : The problem is with your battery. The battery can't produce stable power.

When you go to recovery mode, the power consumption is very low. So, it will stay for some time.

When you turn on the phone, the brand logo is shown, may or may not the Booting is done. Suddenly the phone turns off. Then again turns on and repeat this automatically about 15-20 times.

I have the same issue and after checking for a weak , I found that the battery can't produce the power in a stable manner.

#### How to check.

- Take the battery out.
- check the battery code, power details, etc.
- Find a similar battery.
- Put the battery in the phone and try turning it on.

80% it will work.

Try it and if you are in the 20% part, let me know.

Comment: Tried a battery that previously provided me with a wi-fi hotspot. Nope, didn't work.

Comment: did you checked the voltage and watts of the battery. whether it is same?

Comment: Yep, both "3.8V Li-ion BATTERY 3.8V Li-ion BATTERIE 7.98Wh".

Comment: Seems it was something about the battery after all. See update.

Comment: If the answer seems helped you, consider marking it for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The bootloop happens when  the boot partition is corrupted or in extreme cases the whole eMMC chip is damaged, the phone boots but can't load the system and all ressources.

Among the causes a  defective charger - as you've pointed the phone was left to charge all night long.

Try flashing the phone, this may solve the bootloop.

- Download the firmware for your model, region and same android version or higher.
- Download Odin (Windows) or Heimdall (Mac) and Install it.
- Download Samsung drivers, install them
- Now open Odin, click on AP slot (PDA for lower version)
- Browse to where you have unzipped the firmware
- Select the file (must end with .md5 or .tar)
- Now put the phone to Download mode (Volume down + Home + Power), then press Volume Up
- Connect the phone to the computer the click on START. Wait till the end.
- You phone should reboot and boot normally

**Using Heimdall: follow this [guide](https://www.google.cd/amp/s/sonofgeektalk.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/heimdall-on-a-mac/amp/).**

Let us know if  you experience any errors. We'll try to help.

PS: All your personal data will be wiped.

Comment: You mean download android firmware on my computer? Also, it's a mac, so "Odin (Windows)" cannot be installed on it… Mac version?

Comment: Yes exactly search for your model number firmware (GT-I9300 for international variant). Download Heimdall as you're on Mac

Comment: For Heimdall, I've added a link. check it

Comment: Tried googling "download android 4.4.4 GT-i9301I on Mac", got [this](https://www.google.it/search?q=download+android+4.4.4+GT-i9301I+on+Mac&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5trCWOaUN-KP8Qf9naOgBg), not sure what to open. Anyway, is there any way of saving my data before wiping it? I'd only need to save contacts, SMS's and Whatsapp messages.

Comment: Not sure you can save anything. Go to sammobile.com, you'll find your form

Comment: «Server maintenance (free server) - March 10, 11 and 12. Premium downloads still available». Only premium downloads are available. So I'll come back to this on Monday, if there is no other place to download the firmware from.

Comment: Try http://www.gsm-file.com/

Comment: Apparently there was an issue with the battery. No idea what though. If something comes up, I will come back here and finish the flashing. Thx for your directions.